# Can't set a value on a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm able to send multiple emails at once using Google Spreadsheet.

Now, I'm trying to set a cell with the information that the emails have been sent.

```
function enviar() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  var contact = range.getValues()
  for (var i = 0; i < contact.length; i++) {
    var email = contact[i]
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email[3], email[5], email[6])
    email[7].setValue("enviado")
    email[7].setBackground("green")
    email[7].setFontColor("white")
  }
}
```

The problem is on the three following lines:

```
email[7].setValue("enviado")
email[7].setBackground("green")
email[7].setFontColor("white")
```

I can't find a way to get a range other then:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H2")
```

Another idea was:

```
range[0].getRange()[7].setValue("enviado")
```

None of them worked.

Comment: In your script, you try to use values as the range. I think that the reason of your issue is this. Can I ask you about your question? 1. How are you executing the method for executing the script? 2. In your script, ``range`` retrieved by ``sheet.getActiveRange()`` is used for retrieving values. Will you use as the range by selecting several cells with the constant columns? Is it required to consider the possibility that other range is selected? 3. I cannot understand about ``range[0].getRange()[7].setValue("enviado")``.

Comment: Thank you, @Tanaike. Finally someone that understand it better than me. I have been reading the documentation of Spreadsheet App, but I can't find how to set a cell with a message in a loop.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to resolve your issue. But from your question and your reply, I cannot understand about the vision you want to do yet. So can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Tanaike, 1. I'm executing the method from a button in the sheet. The script is assigned to an image. 2. The sheet receives the answers from a contact form. there are columns for name, phone number, email, and message. I made other 3 columns: subject for contact answer, message, and status, which is set to "sent" once the answer is sent.

Comment: @Tanaike, 2. First, I answer to the contacts in the sheet. Then, I select all the rows (and columns) I added the answer. Finally, I hit the button that execute the script, which sends the messages away. From there on, I add manually "sent" in the last column (status) of each row.

Comment: Thank you for providing the information. Although I can understand about your situation from the information, in order to understand more correctly your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike, 2. That's the part I'm struggling with. The column H is for status update. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H2").setValue("sent")` is ok for only one line. How can I make it automatically if I select 5, 8, 12, 20 lines? `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H3").setValue("sent")
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H4").setValue("sent")
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H5").setValue("sent")
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H6").setValue("sent")`
and so on.

Comment: I`m gonna get you a sample Spreadsheet right the way.

Comment: @Tanaike, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Q7s0rhWSMmxraCWN2cPeSdaHRFhqIwpnT-7iCj7soc/edit#gid=1330297311

Comment: @Tanaike, Contact Form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfoclmaNOhrW0n4LZNlALe4FyQKo2edl_8cRJ6Gw_Oa1KO07g/viewform?usp=sf_link

Comment: Thank you so much for providing more information. I would like to confirm them.

Comment: At the shared spreadsheet, when you push the "SEND" button, you select one row (for example, "A6:G6"?) or all cells (for example, "A2:G6")?

Comment: If I want to send multiple messages, I select A2:H6, then I push the "SEND" button.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit to make it easier to understand. 
`function send() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  var row = range.getValues()
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    var column = row[i]
    GmailApp.sendEmail(column[3], column[5], column[6])
    //sheet.getRange("H2").setValue("sent")
  }
}`

Comment: I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstand your situation, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the shared spreadsheet is used, I could understand below.

- You select "A2:G6" and click "SEND" button.
- When the function `send()` is run, you want to send email with the values retrieved from each row.
- After the emails were sent, you want to put the value of "sent" to the column "H".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- I think that the script above `GmailApp.sendEmail()` is fine.
- In order to put the value of "sent" to the column "H", it uses `range` retrieved by `sheet.getActiveRange()`.

#### Modified script:

```
function send() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  var contact = range.getValues()
  for (var i = 0; i < contact.length; i++) {
    var email = contact[i]
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email[3], email[5], email[6]);
  }
  range.offset(0, 7, range.getNumRows(), 1).setValue("sent"); // Added
}
```

- `offset(0, 7, range.getNumRows(), 1)` means the range of column "H".

  - When "A2:G6" is selected, this becomes "H2:H2". For this range, "sent" is put.
  - In this case, for example, if "A2:F6" is selected, the range becomes "G2:G6".

#### Reference:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset-numrows-numcolumns)

### Added:

If you want to send emails and put the status by selecting only 1 column, how about this script? In this script, for example, "A2:A3" or "C2:C3" is selected, the emails with the values retrieved from each row are sent and "sent" is put to "H2:H3".

```
function send() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  var rng = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, range.getNumRows(), 7); // Added
  var contact = rng.getValues(); // Modified
  for (var i = 0; i < contact.length; i++) {
    var email = contact[i]
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email[3], email[5], email[6]);
  }
  rng.offset(0, 7, range.getNumRows(), 1).setValue("sent"); // Added
}
```

Comment: @Paulo Dos Santos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By the way, I added a sample script. I think that this might be a bit convenient than above sample.

Comment: Awesome! It looks amazing!

Comment: I'm glad that is useful. Thank you, too.